# pass results between queries and display joint results ( google bigquery )

Tags: sql, performance, google-bigquery, with-statement

I want to make a query `q1`, and use the result of `q1` on a second query `q2`.
I want to display all columns of `q1` and `q2`, so that results are based on a common column.

(Please let me know if title is not so clear)

The example below should display columns [`id`, `publisher`, `author`] in the `q1`.
I want to pass them to `q2`, retrieve properties [`id`, `cited_id`, `category`] for all items within the `id` column of `q1`.

As results, for each `id` I want to display all cited_ids and their properties (of both ids and cited_ids).

Alternatively, for better clarity, it is also ok to retrieve an array of cited_ids for each ids, and in a separate query I will decorate my ids and cited_ids with their properties.

Please advise also on the "performance" (I m using bigquery, so if you could explain why a solution is more efficient that would help in saving computational resources!).

I came up with this, but cannot display all columns of q1.

```
WITH q1 AS (

    SELECT id, publisher, a.name
         FROM `db.publications`,
         UNNEST (publisher) as h,
         UNNEST (author) as a
         WHERE h Like '%penguin%'
)
SELECT p.id, c.id AS Cited, c.Category AS Cat 
     FROM `db.publications` AS p, UNNEST(citation) AS c 
     WHERE p.id IN (SELECT id from q1)
```

---

Sample Data:

```
# result of q1
Row | Id | Publisher | Author
1   | item0 | penguin | Bob
2   | item0 | penguin | Alice
3   | item1 | penguin | Charlie
```

I want to find other items that are cited by each unique item in q1 (item0, item1).

I wish to have results in an handy format that could be used in this way:

```
# Citations: books mentioned by item0, item1 ... 
item0 : [item10, item15, item100]
item1 : [item23, item0, item101, item15]
..

# Decorators : information about each book:
Row | Id | Publisher | Author(s) |
```

My question is can achieve both in a single query? 
If so, is it convenient or better to split in two separated queries for lower computational resources? 
My approach is first query a set of books and their decorators, and then use a list of ids to look for their citations. I could not carry decorators along with above example.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would provide better clarity.

Comment: It is not clear to me how is your data in the tables originally. Do you have just one or two tables? Could you provide an example of them? If is just one what you want to achieve is probably doable with just one query.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first part of your question, instead of using `where p.id in(select id from q1)`, use a join to bring in `q1` fields.

```
WITH q1 AS (

    SELECT id, publisher, a.name
         FROM `db.publications`,
         UNNEST (publisher) as h,
         UNNEST (author) as a
         WHERE h Like '%penguin%'
),
joined as (
  select id, p.citation, q1.publisher, q1.name
  from `db.publications` p
  inner join q1 using(id)
)
select id, c.id as Cited, c.Category as Cat
from joined
left join unnest(citation) c
```